# Не работает привязка модели через this

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Посмотрел "лучшие практики angular", и там есть шаблон создания контроллера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю по примеру:

```
(function (angular) {
angular
    .module('test', []);

angular
    .module('test')
    .controller('countryCtrl', countryCtrl);

//countryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function countryCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.country = {
        name: 'Ukraine',
        area: '603 628',
        population: '42 825 883',
        capital: {
            name: 'Kiev'
        }
    };
}
})(angular);
```

Верстка :

```
<div class="box" ng-controller="countryCtrl">
    <h1 class="h1">Страна: {{this.country.name}}</h1>
    <p>Площадь: {{this.country.area}}</p>
    <p>Население: {{this.country.population}}</p>
    <p>Столица: {{this.country.capital.name}}</p>
</div>
```

И ничего не выводится, что я не так делаю ? Спасибо.

Comment: `ng-controller="countryCtrl as vm"` это не зря называется controller as syntax

Comment: @Grundy Такое пишет : Argument 'countryCtrl as vm' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: а какая версия ангуляра?:)

Comment: @Grundy AngularJS v1.0.6)

Comment: старая:-) в ней это не работает - обновляй хотя бы до 1.3.5 или 1.4 ну и естественно лучше всего последнюю типа 1.4.7

Comment: @Grundy спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Данная возможность, использовать контроллер вместо скопа, была представлена в версии 1.1.5 и получила название: `controller As` синтаксис

Она позволяет назначить контроллеру алиас и обращаться напрямую к свойствам и функциям контроллера.

Для этого необходимо прописать в `ng-controller` атрибуте алиас

```
ng-controller="ControllerName as alias"
```

обычно в качестве `alias` указывают `vm` как сокращение от *view model*.

в вашем случае: `ng-controller="countryCtrl as vm"`

Далее в можно обращаться к свойствам контроллера

```
<h1 class="h1">Страна: {{vm.country.name}}</h1>
```

стоит помнить, что скоп никуда не пропадает, и *this* во вью указывает именно на скоп, а так же в скоп добавляется поле c тем же именем, что и алиас, указывающее на контроллер.